How to specify the Context struct type by it's location at other files if it's name is same?
I want to set the Context struct type by it's location at the file which it's names are same. Here is a PoC what I want.
pub mod instructions;
pub use instructions::*;

#[program]
pub mod myProgram {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize(
        ctx: Context<instructions::initialize::Initialize>,
        receipt_token_name: String,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        instructions::initialize::handler(
            ctx,
            receipt_token_name,
        )
    }

    pub fn deposit_sol_initialize(
        ctx: Context<instructions::deposit_sol::Initialize>,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        instructions::deposit_sol::initialize(ctx)
    }
}


But this causes syntax error. Here is the error logs.
error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate`
  --> programs/myProgram/src/lib.rs:20:1
   |
20 | #[program]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^ could not find `__client_accounts_instructions` in the crate root
   |
   = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `program` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0573]: expected type, found module `instructions`
  --> programs/myProgram/src/lib.rs:25:22
   |
25 |         ctx: Context<instructions::initialize::Initialize>,
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: a struct with a similar name exists (notice the capitalization): `Instructions`
  --> src/sysvar/instructions.rs:56:1
   |
   = note: similarly named struct `Instructions` defined here

error[E0425]: cannot find function `try_accounts` in module `instructions`
  --> programs/myProgram/src/lib.rs:20:1
   |
20 | #[program]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^ not found in `instructions`
   |
   = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `program` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0573]: expected type, found module `instructions`
  --> programs/myProgram/src/lib.rs:41:22
   |
41 |         ctx: Context<instructions::deposit_sol::Initialize>,
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: a struct with a similar name exists (notice the capitalization): `Instructions`
  --> src/sysvar/instructions.rs:56:1
   |
   = note: similarly named struct `Instructions` defined here

Isn't it possible to set multiple same named Context struct type at the other files and use it at lib.rs file at once?
